# accessing value in a JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I have a Json object which has the following data

{\"data\":{\"pdp0:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"15104\",\"bytes\":\"9059817\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"9480\",\"bytes\":\"1687801\"}},\"gre0:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"}},\"tunl0:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"}},\"usb0:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"0\",\"bytes\":\"0\"}},\"lo:\":{\"recv\":{\"packets\":\"48300\",\"bytes\":\"2616703\"},\"sent\":{\"packets\":\"48300\",\"bytes\":\"2616703\"}}},\"ver\":\"1.4\",\"type\":\"netdev\",\"date\":\"2011-4-13 14:10:21\",\"user\":\"351863047772880\",\"time_stamp\":1305313821541}

If I want to access the data in data->pdp0->recv->packets   (here the value is 15104) which function should I use?

thanks
sarath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plain old org.json package to get the nested objects:

```
int packets = new JSONObject(str) // str is your JSON string as above
                 .getJSONObject("data")
                 .getJSONObject("pdp0")
                 .getJSONObject("recv")
                 .getInt("packets");
```

API details here: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Hi, when I use the code I am getting an error that str should be of type Map, But I declared str as JSONobject

Comment: `str` was meant to be the `String` you mention above. If it is already a `JSONObject`, then proceed directly to do `str.getJSONObject("data");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use what Aleadam suggested. However, you would be better of using [GSON for java objects](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) because it allows you to serialise and de-serialise your JSON to and from your Java Objects.